# Microsoft Graph returns unexpected HTTP code on SharePoint throttling

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, throttling

When hitting a throttle limit on SharePoint, MS Graph returns an HTTP 304 with a redirect to /_layouts/15/throttle.html instead of a 429 error on SharePoint endpoints (sites, lists, my documents from OneDrive). Is this intended and should we check for this in our code, or is this a bug? I couldn't find any known issues or documentation on this.

We only started seeing this due to the the SPO throttle issues (see; https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4336). Hitting a general graph throttle still returns the expected 429.

Comment: The response from Graph that ends up returning the redirect should have a `client-request-id` header - could you update your question to include the value? It'll help give us an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Hi brad, in the linked issue I've posted a screenshot which has a (client-) request-id for you guys. :)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I should have checked first :D